# Class definition error when retrieving related entites with DQL query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to retrieve a number of related entities in my Symfony application as follows:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
   'SELECT i, c, prod, prov
    FROM MyBundle:CustomerItem i
    JOIN i.customer c
    JOIN i.product prod
    JOIN prod.provider prov
    JOIN');
```

On execution, I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT i, c,': Error: Class '' is not defined.
```

The attributes `customer`, `product`, and `provider` all exist as fields representing the underlying entity relations.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working using the query builder:

```
    $query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('prov')
        ->select('c.id')
        ->innerJoin('prov.products', 'prod')
        ->innerJoin('prod.customerItems', 'ci')
        ->innerJoin('ci.customer', 'c')
        ->where('prov.id = :brand')
        ->getQuery();
```